# IE11 отображает шрифт только жирным при любом font-weight

Tags: css, internet-explorer, шрифты

Столкнулся с проблемой, что IE11 при любом значении `font-weight` отображает шрифт жирным. Шрифт [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto).

Шрифт в Chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шрифт в IE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обойти эту проблему?

Использование `font-weight: lighter` или `font-weight: 100` влияет на отображение.

Comment: Можете привести пример? В меня был похожий случай. Но отображался шрифт не жирный, а вдвойне жирный, из-за того, что на 2 элементах был стиль `font-weight: bold;`

Comment: @Zergatul добавил скрины. или код нужен?

Comment: `font-weight: initial;` не решает проблему? выше по иерархии элементов ни на ком нет `bold`?

Comment: @Zergatul вообще все упоминания веса убрал, жирнота управляется везде, кроме ie

Comment: нужен код и строка подключения шрифта

Comment: @Grundy подключаю через вебпак, там целый список с файлами .otf, затем просто в css body использую этот шрифт

Comment: Пробовали на для IE11 выбрать fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300 - т.е. самый тонкий подключать?
На крайний случай можете сделать шрифт меньше, растянуть с transform scale и добавить чуть тени...

Comment: @CodeGust да, я работал и файлами шрифтов в вебпаке,и в head подключал гугл-шрифт с всеми значениями жирности без результатов, именно ie жирнит